# Combining two widgets with each other

Tags: java, android, xml, view, widget

First, Sorry my English not good enough. Iam new in Android development. I have many widgets. Can I make them in one widget and when I need to add them I just add. Because Iam creating a library and I need to publish it on github.

```
<com.example.custom.view>
... />
```

These are all the views(widgets) I need them in one widget and I can add it in a layout.

```xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hscroll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/vscroll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/linear4"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is [that](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts) what you are looking for?

Comment: @AndreiShpakovskiy Yes and no. If you install a library from github. The author says add <example.customview>... I need to make like that not include I need a custom view

Comment: To make it work like you've described, you need to create a custom view by extending one of View classes. Check [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/142-android-custom-view-tutorial) out

Comment: What you want is called a *compound view* - there are a lot of tutorials if you search for that, and there's some info on the Android site: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/custom-components#compound

Comment: Is there courses about that ?